# Github API Create issue Markdown not rendering

Tags: github, github-api, github-flavored-markdown

I am creating a GitHub issue via the API using a script.

```
    var labels = [];
    labels.push('proposal');

    var body = \n*Title:* ' + title + '\n##Abstract: \n' + abstract; 

    var payload = {
        "title": title,
        "body": body,
        "labels": labels
    };
 
    var options = {
        "method": "POST",
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
    };
  
   options.headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(handle + ":" + token)};

   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/"+org+"/"+repo+"/issues", options);
```

The issue is getting posted correctly to Github, except that the markdown is not rendered when I look at the issue in Github. It just shows up as ## and * instead of headers and italics. If I go ahead and edit the issue manually in Github and mark the headers using the visual editor, it puts in another # and then renders it correctly. How do I get it to show correctly using the API?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

The markdown text in the body is not correctly formatted. Every markdown syntax character should be having whitespace around it, which in OP's case is absent.

**Code :**

```js
var reqHeaders = new Headers();
reqHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer <token>");
reqHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var rawBody = JSON.stringify({
  "title": "Markdown not rendering due to malformed markdown text in request body ",
  "body": "\n*Title:* This is some title \n## Abstract: \n And this is some abstract",
  "assignees": [
    "akmalick"
  ],
  "labels": [
    "bug",
    "good first issue",
    "help wanted"
  ]
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: reqHeaders,
  body: rawBody
};

fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/issues", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

**Below is the end result :**

[image]

Comment: as the data is passed in JSON format, this won't work. simply passing the correct markdown content as a string in the `body` works for me.

Comment: Thanks @AshutoshKumar for bringing it up. Realized that and updated my answer.